# "Stop" a css transition mid-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a toggleClass applied to a button on click. The button rotates and fades and has a duration. If you rapidly click the button it'll cause the rotation to go out of sync. Usually to handle this you'd use `stop` in jQuery. I was trying to keep my styling in my stylesheet though. Is there anyway to jump to the beginning or end if you click in-between a transition?

```js
$('.drawer-dropdown-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('drawer-dropdown-button--active');
  
  const height = $('.list').height() > 0 ? 0 : $('.list').prop('scrollHeight');
  
  $('.list').css('height', `${height}px`);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button {
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 14px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:before,
.drawer-dropdown-button:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0076ff;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:before {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:after {
  height: 14px;
  width: 2px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button.drawer-dropdown-button--active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.drawer-dropdown-button.drawer-dropdown-button--active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:hover:before,
.drawer-dropdown-button:hover:after {
  background: #3398ff;
}

.list {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="drawer-dropdown-button"></button>

<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What browser are you experiencing the issue in? I just tried it in chrome and mashed the mouse as fast as I could and it was fine.

Comment: I'm in chrome as well. Let me see if I can put a dropdown menu in there to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: @MathewBerg Updated. Take note. If you click in the middle of the transition, the button will form into the minus symbol when it should be the plus when the menu's height is 0.

Comment: Ah ok, I see it now. I got it to show nothing when it should show a list (Icon is a minus). I don't know of any way to stop the transition, my suggestion would be to maybe add a check in JS to not toggle the class while in transitioning but this means you'll have to keep track of that length of time outside it. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be `element.css({'pointer-events':'none'})` this way you disable all the incoming clicks.

After the animation is done you can do

```
setTimeout(function() {
        element.css({'pointer-events':''})
      }, 300)
```

```js
$('.drawer-dropdown-button').on('click', function() {
  var element = $(this)
  element.toggleClass('drawer-dropdown-button--active');
  element.css({'pointer-events':'none'})
  const height = $('.list').height() > 0 ? 0 :     $('.list').prop('scrollHeight');
  
  $('.list').css('height', `${height}px`);
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.css({'pointer-events':''})
  }, 300)
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button {
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 14px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:before,
.drawer-dropdown-button:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0076ff;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:before {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:after {
  height: 14px;
  width: 2px;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button.drawer-dropdown-button--active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.drawer-dropdown-button.drawer-dropdown-button--active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.drawer-dropdown-button:hover:before,
.drawer-dropdown-button:hover:after {
  background: #3398ff;
}

.list {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="drawer-dropdown-button"></button>

<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
</ul>
```